# Android aar's have stopped building with extractDebugAnnotations com/intellij/psi/PsiJavaFile android

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

My build have recently stopped working for an open source gradle/android project. They've been working just fine until today (Oct 10 2016). I run a build matrix across multiple versions (on travis) of gradle and the gradle android plugin. Essentially, it's now failing on gradle 3.0 and 3, both with the gradle android 2.2.0 plugin. Other versions using different android plugins are ok. It's only the 2.2.0 plugin that's failing.

The part that baffles me is the error message

```
:hello-world-aar:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:hello-world-aar:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:hello-world-aar:checkDebugManifest
:hello-world-aar:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:hello-world-aar:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:hello-world-aar:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:hello-world-aar:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:hello-world-aar:prepareOrgOsmdroidOsmdroidAndroid541ReleaseLibrary
:hello-world-aar:prepareDebugDependencies
:hello-world-aar:compileDebugAidl
:hello-world-aar:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:hello-world-aar:compileLint
:hello-world-aar:copyDebugLint SKIPPED
:hello-world-aar:compileDebugRenderscript
:hello-world-aar:generateDebugBuildConfig
:hello-world-aar:generateDebugResValues
:hello-world-aar:generateDebugResources
:hello-world-aar:mergeDebugResources
:hello-world-aar:processDebugManifest
:hello-world-aar:processDebugResources
:hello-world-aar:generateDebugSources
:hello-world-aar:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
:hello-world-aar:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:hello-world-aar:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
:hello-world-aar:extractDebugAnnotations FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':hello-world-aar:extractDebugAnnotations'.

> com/intellij/psi/PsiJavaFile
```

Again this is on an Android Archive (AAR) project. I've searched and can't find much on that class. It's not referenced anywhere in my code. My best guess is that google changed a support library or something that broke something. I'm also building from the command line via travis. I have no idea where the intellij stuff is coming from.

Comment: I started seeing this today also one my Jenkins build within a couple different aar projects.

Comment: I am seeing it from a Gradle build using AIDE for Android. Problem just started not long ago...

Comment: https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle looks like a new version was pushed out center, 2.2.1

Comment: A bug has been filed here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=224910

Answer (score 3):

fixed by clearing the cache with:

```
rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches/
```

Answer (score 2):

This has beed fixed according to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=224910 . You can rebuild your project with gradle command line after clear gracle cache locally (rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches/)

Also , you need do same operation on your CI agent .

Comment: still broken on travis

Comment: n, fixed now. very irritating

Answer (score 2):

I just faced the same issue.
The problem in my project was an empty IntDef.
If clearing gradle cache doesn't work, check if you don't have empty Def in your code, and remove them.

`@IntDef({})` or `@StringDef({})` ...

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was having a problem running `.gradlew library:assemble` on an Apple M1 and was caused by some `@IntDef`.
Maybe this comment is useful for other people. The error was the following:
`Execution failed for task ':library:extractReleaseAnnotations'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.lint.AndroidLintWorkAction
   > Internal error: unexpected lint return value -1`